# Отобразить часть html кода в Activity android

Tags: java, android

Есть часть HTML кода на сайте который выполняет некоторый функционал(данный функионал связан с 1С базой), так вот вопрос.
Можно ли как то отобразить этот функционал в своем приложении( например есть поле для ввода и кнопка поиска), сделать xml разметку в приложении и подключить ссылкой к ним эти поля или все таки придется напрямую подключать в базе 1С что бы искал там?

Можно не решение а просто хотя бы ссылку на теорию для изучения как связать веб функции с разметкой XML андроида буду благодарен.

Если говорить проще я хочу сделать 2-3 вьюшки в андроиде и что бы они просто были связаны с сайтом и данные после нажатия на кнопку парсились с сайта в приложении.

Comment: вообще по логике, если вы разрешите работать внутри webview с вашим html то он я думаю будет обрабатывать ваши действия так же как и обычный браузер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении в webview разметки можно связывать его с JS. Вот например:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

делаете интерфейс для работы:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

и подключаете его к виджету:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

[Вот есть документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview), где описано возможное решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию и пример, очень полезно вышло))